# Overlaying a UIView on a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I have an application with 6 view controllers all working fine and switching between each other. However, I want to overlay one of them with a UIView of graphics (Histogram or Line Chart, etc) which has a transparent background. How do I do this? Or, alternatively how do I switch from a UIViewController to a UIView  *and back*.  There is no interaction from the graphic (UIView) so I could use a modalview. What's the best way to achieve either?

Comment: Why not just make the add the view as a subview?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your overlay view is in `overlayView` variable. Simply put this line in your view controller ...

```
[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

... and do not forget to set frame or proper autoresizing mask.